# Query a certain page with Google Analytics API C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to know the page views for a certain page/url only. 
Is there a way to add the url to the Google query? Baseurl doesn't seem to work.

```
DataQuery PageViewQuery = new DataQuery(DataFeedUrl)
{
    Ids = ProfileID,
    Dimensions = "ga:date",
    Metrics = "ga:pageviews",
    Sort = "ga:date",
    GAStartDate = (DateTime.Now).AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    GAEndDate = (DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try ga:pagePath (plus  ga:hostname if you need to retrieve a full URL), or if you have unique page titles ga:pageTitle should be a valid workaround.

Full documentation of dimensions and metric is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.

Comment: would this be a filter?   Filters = "ga:pagePath = /page?en=1" ? If so, this isn't working

Comment: I got that working, admittedly not with c#. In other api implementations you need a double equation mark (ga:pagePath == /page?en=1) for filters, maybe it's the same here ?